# Can't save all matlibplots to pdf - missing some graphs (IPython)

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, graph, ipython

I have a script that I run in IPython, and basically takes an input .csv file of `gene_names` and pushes them into this for loop, where

```
with open('C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Book1.csv', 'rU') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
with PdfPages('poopyheadjoe04.pdf') as pdf:
    for row in reader:
        gene_name = row
        probe_exclusion_keyword = []
        print gene_name
```

The gene_name values from this list(in the .csv file) is then fed into a line, `if inference_method == "approximate_random"`: (in Scripts.py)

```
with open('C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Book1.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with PdfPages('poopyheadjoe04.pdf') as pdf:
        for row in reader:
            gene_name = row
            probe_exclusion_keyword = []
            print gene_name

            print "Fetching probe ids for gene %s" % gene_name
            probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes(gene_name)
            print "Found %s probes: %s" % (len(probes_dict), ", ".join(probes_dict.values()))

            if probe_exclusion_keyword:
                probes_dict = {probe_id: probe_name for (probe_id, probe_name) in probes_dict.iteritems() if not args.probe_exclusion_keyword in probe_name}
                print "Probes after applying exclusion cryterion: %s" % (", ".join(probes_dict.values()))

            print "Fetching expression values for probes %s" % (", ".join(probes_dict.values()))
            expression_values, well_ids, donor_names = get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(    
            probes_dict.keys())
            print "Found data from %s wells sampled across %s donors" % (len(well_ids), len(set(donor_names)))

            print "Combining information from selected probes"
            combined_expression_values = combine_expression_values(
            expression_values, method=probes_reduction_method)

            print "Translating locations of the wells to MNI space"
            mni_coordinates = get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)

            print "Checking values of the provided NIFTI file at well locations"
            nifti_values = get_values_at_locations(
            stat_map, mni_coordinates, mask_file=mask, radius=radius, verbose=True)

        # preparing the data frame
            names = ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name, "donor ID"]
            data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
            [nifti_values, combined_expression_values, donor_names]).T, columns=names)
            data = data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
            len_before = len(data)
            data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
            nans = len_before - len(data)

            if nans > 0:
                print "%s wells fall outside of the mask" % nans

            if inference_method == "fixed":
                print "Performing fixed effect analysis"
                fixed_effects(data, ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name])

            **if inference_method == "approximate_random":**
                print "Performing approximate random effect analysis"
                approximate_random_effects(
                data, ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name], "donor ID")
                print "poopy"
                pdf.savefig()
                plt.ion() #should i add ion() here?

            if inference_method == "bayesian_random":
                print "Fitting Bayesian hierarchical model"
                bayesian_random_effects(
                data, ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name], "donor ID", n_samples, n_burnin)

        # if __name__ == '__main__':    #What exactly does this do? Start trigger for the script to run?
        # main()
```

that triggers `approximate_random_effects`(in Analysis.py) to **plot two graphs**, the **violinplot** and the **lmplot**:

```
def approximate_random_effects(data, labels, group):

    correlation_per_donor = {}
    for donor_id in set(data[group]):
        correlation_per_donor[donor_id], _, _, _, _ = linregress(list(data[labels[0]][data[group] == donor_id]),
                                                       list(data[labels[1]][data[group] == donor_id]))
    average_slope = np.array(correlation_per_donor.values()).mean()
    t, p_val = ttest_1samp(correlation_per_donor.values(), 0)
    print "Averaged slope across donors = %g (t=%g, p=%g)"%(average_slope, t, p_val)
    sns.violinplot([correlation_per_donor.values()], inner="points", names=["donors"])
    plt.ylabel("Linear regression slopes between %s and %s"%(labels[0],labels[1]))
    plt.axhline(0, color="red")

    sns.lmplot(labels[0], labels[1], data, hue=group, col=group, col_wrap=3)
    plt.ion()

    return average_slope, t, p_val
```

I'm trying to save both graphs for all the gene_names into a pdf file, by roughly following "[Saving multiple figures to one pdf file in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435769/saving-multiple-figures-to-one-pdf-file-in-matplotlib)" and the `matplotlib.PdfPages` approach.

**However, in the pdf file, I am only getting the lmplot for all my gene_names and NOT the violin plot.** What do I do to fix this?

Thanks! Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: if you comment out `pdf.savefig()`, so you see the two plots or do you only see one? also, should these two plots be on the same figure (and same pdf page), or are they separate?

Comment: @JulienSpronck For the first question, by default it runs to give 2 plots(violin + lmplot) on two different windows, so yes i get 2 plots. Second question, the plots for each gene_name should be in different window, but they just have to be in linear vertical order in the pdf, i.e. same page but separate plot pictures.

Comment: To have the two plots on separate pages in the pdf, you can plot them in separate figures and call `pdf.savefig()` for each figure. However, if you want the two plots on the same page, then you should create two sub-plots on the same figure. Which one do you need/want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is creating two figures, one for each plots, but you only call `pdf.savefig()` once after the second figure is created, therefore only saving the second figure.

If you want one figure per page in your pdf, you need to call `pdf.savefig()` twice: once after creating each plot.

I would recommend that you change the structure of your program a bit, so you can save the pdf after each plot:

```
def approximate_random_effects(data, labels, group):

    correlation_per_donor = {}
    for donor_id in set(data[group]):
        correlation_per_donor[donor_id], _, _, _, _ = linregress(list(data[labels[0]][data[group] == donor_id]),
                                                       list(data[labels[1]][data[group] == donor_id]))
    average_slope = np.array(correlation_per_donor.values()).mean()
    t, p_val = ttest_1samp(correlation_per_donor.values(), 0)
    print "Averaged slope across donors = %g (t=%g, p=%g)"%(average_slope, t, p_val)
    with PdfPages('poopyheadjoe04.pdf') as pdf:
        fig = plt.figure()
        sns.violinplot([correlation_per_donor.values()], inner="points", names=["donors"])
        plt.ylabel("Linear regression slopes between %s and %s"%(labels[0],labels[1]))
        plt.axhline(0, color="red")
        pdf.savefig(fig) ## Saving first figure

        fig = plt.figure()
        sns.lmplot(labels[0], labels[1], data, hue=group, col=group, col_wrap=3)
        pdf.savefig(fig) ## Saving second figure

    return average_slope, t, p_val
```

You then need to delete in your main program the lines `with PdfPages('poopyheadjoe04.pdf') as pdf:`, `pdf.savefig()` and `plt.ion()`.

If you need the two plots on the same pdf page, you need change the `violinplot` and `lmplot` in such a way that they use different axes on the same figure.