# Not saving all matplotlib graphs from script output?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, graph, ipython

I have a script that I run in IPython, and basically takes an input .csv file of `gene_names` and pushes them into this for loop, where

```
with open('C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Book1.csv', 'rU') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
with PdfPages('poopyheadjoe04.pdf') as pdf:
    for row in reader:
        gene_name = row
        probe_exclusion_keyword = []
        print gene_name
```

The gene_name values from this list(in the .csv file) is then fed into a line, `if inference_method == "approximate_random"`: (in Scripts.py)

```
with open('C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Book1.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with PdfPages('poopyheadjoe04.pdf') as pdf:
        for row in reader:
            gene_name = row
            probe_exclusion_keyword = []
            print gene_name

            print "Fetching probe ids for gene %s" % gene_name
            probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes(gene_name)
            print "Found %s probes: %s" % (len(probes_dict), ", ".join(probes_dict.values()))

            if probe_exclusion_keyword:
                probes_dict = {probe_id: probe_name for (probe_id, probe_name) in probes_dict.iteritems() if not args.probe_exclusion_keyword in probe_name}
                print "Probes after applying exclusion cryterion: %s" % (", ".join(probes_dict.values()))

            print "Fetching expression values for probes %s" % (", ".join(probes_dict.values()))
            expression_values, well_ids, donor_names = get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(    
            probes_dict.keys())
            print "Found data from %s wells sampled across %s donors" % (len(well_ids), len(set(donor_names)))

            print "Combining information from selected probes"
            combined_expression_values = combine_expression_values(
            expression_values, method=probes_reduction_method)

            print "Translating locations of the wells to MNI space"
            mni_coordinates = get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)

            print "Checking values of the provided NIFTI file at well locations"
            nifti_values = get_values_at_locations(
            stat_map, mni_coordinates, mask_file=mask, radius=radius, verbose=True)

        # preparing the data frame
            names = ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name, "donor ID"]
            data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
            [nifti_values, combined_expression_values, donor_names]).T, columns=names)
            data = data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
            len_before = len(data)
            data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
            nans = len_before - len(data)

            if nans > 0:
                print "%s wells fall outside of the mask" % nans

            if inference_method == "fixed":
                print "Performing fixed effect analysis"
                fixed_effects(data, ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name])

            **if inference_method == "approximate_random":**
                print "Performing approximate random effect analysis"
                approximate_random_effects(
                data, ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name], "donor ID")
                print "poopy"
                pdf.savefig()
                plt.ion() #should i add ion() here?

            if inference_method == "bayesian_random":
                print "Fitting Bayesian hierarchical model"
                bayesian_random_effects(
                data, ["NIFTI values", "%s expression" % gene_name], "donor ID", n_samples, n_burnin)

        # if __name__ == '__main__':    #What exactly does this do? Start trigger for the script to run?
        # main()
```

that triggers `approximate_random_effects`(in Analysis.py) to **plot two graphs**, the **violinplot** and the **lmplot**:

```
def approximate_random_effects(data, labels, group):

    correlation_per_donor = {}
    for donor_id in set(data[group]):
        correlation_per_donor[donor_id], _, _, _, _ = linregress(list(data[labels[0]][data[group] == donor_id]),
                                                       list(data[labels[1]][data[group] == donor_id]))
    average_slope = np.array(correlation_per_donor.values()).mean()
    t, p_val = ttest_1samp(correlation_per_donor.values(), 0)
    print "Averaged slope across donors = %g (t=%g, p=%g)"%(average_slope, t, p_val)
    sns.violinplot([correlation_per_donor.values()], inner="points", names=["donors"])
    plt.ylabel("Linear regression slopes between %s and %s"%(labels[0],labels[1]))
    plt.axhline(0, color="red")

    sns.lmplot(labels[0], labels[1], data, hue=group, col=group, col_wrap=3)
    plt.ion()

    return average_slope, t, p_val
```

I'm trying to save both graphs for all the gene_names into a pdf file, by roughly following "[Saving multiple figures to one pdf file in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435769/saving-multiple-figures-to-one-pdf-file-in-matplotlib)" and the `matplotlib.PdfPages` approach.

**However, in the pdf file, I am only getting the lmplot for all my gene_names and NOT the violin plot.** And interestingly, adding print to `def approximate_random_effects` (of Analysis.py) does not reflect any output.  What do I do to fix this?

Thanks! Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two different axes for the plots, one for the violin plot, and one for the imshow plot.  At the top of your approximate_random_effects function add

```
fig, (ax_left, ax_right) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(6,3)) # change figsize to the size you want, default is ugly with two plots
```

or

```
fig, (ax_top, ax_bottom) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(3, 6)) # change figsize to the size you want, default is ugly with two plots
```

depending on if you want top and bottom or side by side.  For the rest of the this answer, assume side by side.

Now you need to change your plotting calls by adding ax=ax_left and ax=ax_right

```
sns.violinplot([correlation_per_donor.values()], inner="points", names=["donors"], ax=ax_left)
```

and

```
sns.lmplot(labels[0], labels[1], data, hue=group, col=group, col_wrap=3, ax=ax_right)
```

Comment: Hey @Kyle, thanks so much for the tip! I have a new problem though. My violinplot produces only 1 graph(left side), so it's ok. But the lmplots give 6 graphs(they are superimposed on each other if i use your current ans), how should i modify your answer then? Thanks lots!